# problem with JNDI

Tags: java, websphere, jndi

I have code which uses JNDI.The code snippet as as follows:

```
EntityManager createEM(String JNDI ){

  EntityManager em = null;
   try{
   InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
   em = (EntityManager) ic.lookup(JNDI);
   return em;
   }
 catch (Exception ex){
   LOG.Error("error in creating em");
   ex.printStackTrace();

}

}
```

Now i get error .The control enters catch block.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/persistence not found in context "java:".
[12/28/10 15:51:07:086 GMT+05:30] 00000081 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1837)
[12/28/10 15:51:07:086 GMT+05:30] 00000081 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1166)
[12/28/10 15:51:07:086 GMT+05:30] 00000081 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1095)
[12/28/10 15:51:07:086 GMT+05:30] 00000081 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookup(UrlContextImpl.java:1233)
[12/28/10 15:51:07:086 GMT+05:30] 00000081 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookup(javaURLContextImpl.java:394)
[12/28/10 15:51:07:086 GMT+05:30] 00000081 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:214)
[12/28/10 15:51:07:086 GMT+05:30] 00000081 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:154)
[12/28/10 15:51:07:086 GMT+05:30] 00000081 SystemErr     R  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

I have 2 projects say A and B.Now project B has the above method and from project A i am calling mehod from project B.persistent.xml is presnt only in project A.Do i need to place persistent.xml in project A too?I also get the folloing as a part of exception

```
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/env/persistence not found in context "java:".
```

What may be the cause.Am using websphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of the problem is a little sloppy:

> persistent.xml is presnt only in project A.Do i need to place persistent.xml in project A too?

I take it you mean: *persistence.xml is present only in project B. Do I need to place persistence.xml in project A too?*

What exactly is the setup? Are both projects deployed to the same server? Are they on different servers? Is project A accessing a remote session bean of project B? What projects are we talking about? Web projects, EJB projects? EAR projects with both Web and EJB projects in them?

I don't think it's supported that you ship an entity manager from one application to the other. The idea is that a client calls a remote bean, then this remote bean obtains a local entity manager, does some work with it and returns the results. If A is your client, then A certainly **does not** need to have a local persistence.xml.

Your problem might well be that the entity manager you're after is simply not available under the name you think it is. `java:comp/env/persistence` obviously doesn't exist. Normally an entity manager doesn't appear automatically in JNDI. If B was a servlet, you would need something like this:

```
<persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>yourpu</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

If B was an EJB session bean, you need something like this:

```
@Stateless
@PersistenceUnit(name="persistence", unitName="yourpu")
public class BBean implements BRemoteInterface {
    // some code here...
}
```

After this, the entity manager would be available under `java:comp/env/persistence`, but **only** when the JNDI lookup is being initiated from that servlet or bean. java:comp/env is a relative context, that is different for each location that a lookup is done on it.

The least you could do is simply printing your `java:comp/env` context from B and see what's in there exactly. See this simple example how to do such printing: http://tripoverit.blogspot.com/2007/03/print-jndi-tree.html

Comment: <persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>yourpu</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>

Comment: Great! So B was a servlet after all it appears ;) The above fragment needed to go in web.xml btw for other people reading this.

Comment: Hi, am getting a new problem now .I have posted a new post for that , can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633748/concurrency-problem-when-trying-to-delete-in-jpa

Answer (score 0):

Did u define the connection named persistence in your websphere configuration?

The error is saying u didnt define any named 'persistence'

Comment: thanks for replying.I dont know where i should give those entries.I am just using some apis developed by someone else .Can you  please let me know where i should mention those properties?

Comment: You need to go through the admin console and set up the connection settings including database type (jdbc driver), ip address and credentials. You will also need to add the jdbc driver jar file. Have a look at IBMs documentation or search online for full details. Here is one :  http://www.enavigo.com/2007/05/14/setting-up-a-jndi-data-source-in-websphere-6061/

Comment: i updated the original post , can you please provide your comments on it

Comment: Well if the there is something you know is evidently different between the 2 projects you should try to get them in sync and see if suddenly the failing project works. Websphere can't invent the persistence settings from thin air, so it either needs the respective persistence.xml or it needs it to be defined somewhere in its admin console. It needs to know the database settings etc. to create your EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug the application running on websphere. It is possible to do this. I'd suggest you run the app in debug mode and break point at the jndi lookup point and then you can interrogate the state of the jndi context.

Comment: i cannot set breakpoint.My app is dam heavy and if i run my server in debug mode it doesnot start

Comment: that can happen. What contexts are you running the lookup in? i.e. EJB/servlet/startup listener?

Comment: i updated the original post , can you please provide your comments on it

Comment: i updated my post .IS it because of unable to find persistence.xml?

Comment: don't think so, haven't used jndi to register my entity manager factory so I'm not sure