# concurrency problem when trying to delete in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have 2 EARs 1_EAR and 2_EAR (these has websearvices and other code).Now i have 1 project DB_prj that is used for interacting with database.Now all projects 1_EAR,2_EAR, DB_prj have a persistence.xml in their  respective meta-inf folder.Now  only 1_EAR and 2_EAR have web.xml in it. 2_EAR is a new project which is developed by our team. 1_EAr is working fine.Now when i try to delete any record by using class  developed which i placed in 2_EAR my code hangs and times out.To delete a record i call API from  DB_prj which works fine when called from 1_EAR.In web.xml of 1_EAR and 2_EAR i have following in common. web.xml of 1_EAR has many other things whic are not present in web.xml of 2_EAR.

```
<persistence-context-ref>
 <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/XYZPersist</persistence-context-ref-name>
 <persistence-unit-name>XYZPersist</persistence-unit-name>
 </persistence-context-ref>
```

Can any one help me in solving this problem?The above code i had placed in web.xml of 2_EAR after somone answered my  post @ [problem with JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545593/problem-with-jndi)

Comment: Do reads, updates, and saves work fine on 2_EAR?

Comment: read, and inset new worsk fine works fine

Comment: Am trying to solve this issue since last 5 days,Can any one help?

Comment: Try printing a thread dump while the delete is happening to see why it is waiting. Could it be a database lock, for instance?

Comment: Add this to your persistence.xml
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
</properties>

I bet that there is database locking.  This should help you figure out where that is happening.

Comment: most databases have a way of showing deadlocked transactions.  i would recommend pursuing that course.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be your EAR#2 resolves context via JNDI, but the context was bound by EAR#1, with EAR#1 classloader; therefore somewhere deep in the belly of persistence API you probably get a ClassCastException because the class, though has the same name and package, was loaded by a different class loader.

My point is that two EARs should have different JNDI names for their persistence units. From your post it looks they are the same.

(Actually, the mention that insert/update works fine contradicts my hypothesis, but who knows.)